# How can I compose and send email in Thunderbird from commandline?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, thunderbird

I use this command to send a logfile with Thunderbird:

```
thunderbird -compose "subject='test',to='test@mail.test',body=$output,attachment='/home/test/scan.log'"
```

That launches and shows Thunderbird's prefilled edit-message-window and I have to press the Send button manually.

How can I send email automatically?

[image: screenshot thunderbird]

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it is possible, using `xdotool`. Though not "proper", it is possible.

You can (modify to suit your purpose) and save this to ~/bin/send-mail

```
#!/bin/bash

output='testing'

thunderbird -compose "subject='test mail',to='test@mail.com',body=$output" &
sleep 2                  # Wait for the window to open
xdotool mousemove 55 105 # Find the exact position of the send button manually
sleep 0.25               # Might not be needed
xdotool click 1          # Click it
echo "Done!"
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x bin/send-mail
```

Addionally, add it to your cron job. But this sure can be risky.

Comment: You can also send an HTML-formatted email using `message=/path/to/file.html` instead of `body=$output`. For more options, see [Command line arguments](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_-_Thunderbird) or type `thunderbird --help`.

Answer (score 3):

Thunderbird doesn't support automatically sending an email using the command line (i.e. non interactively). This question was answered here - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1144493

It suggests you communicate directly with the relevant SMTP server instead of using a mail client like Thunderbird.

Possibly using PHP -http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/sending-email-from-site/using-the-php-mail-function-to-send-emails

Comment: If you are on the command line, one is probably better off with `sendmail` rather than tinkering around with PHP or JavaScript.